# XSLT create complex SVG visualisation minimizing line crossings etc

Tags: performance, xslt, svg, visualization

This is no actual single coding problem, rather a problem of the right approach to a complex issue.

So, I have built a rather complex svg visualisation of my XML data using xslt. It looks like this:

[image: example of how my svg visualisation looks]
<sub>(source: [erksst.de](http://www.erksst.de/daten/svg%20vis.jpg))</sub>

This is just a small sample of the whole data. There are two or three rows. Each row could contain up to 160 yellow boxes.

(The yellow boxes are letter collections, the blue/grey boxes single letters, the lines represent their way of dissemination.)

It works well so far but I want to optimize it:

(1) minimize the number of line crossing

(2) minimize the number of lines crossing a blue/grey box

(3) minimize the lines being too near to another line.

To achieve this there are things to vary:

(a) The broadest row (in the sample it is the third) is fix. It can't be moved. But the other (two) can be moved in the range of the width of the broadest row. I.e. in my example the yellow box of the second row could be moved some 160 pixels to the right.

(b) Furthermore, in the two smaller rows the margin between the yellow boxes could be varied. In my example there is just one per line. But of course there could be more than one yellow box in the two smaller rows.

(c) The order of the yellow boxes within a row could be altered.

So, many possibilites to realize this visualisation.
The problem is the performance time.

I have started with the line crossing problem by using a function which kind of pre-builds the visualisation and calculates the number of crossings.
The variation with the smallest number of crossings is actually built in the output.
The problem is the time it needs. The transformation with just 100 possibilites and my hole XML data took 90 seconds. Doesn't sound like much, but taking into account that 100 variations are just a very small part of all theoritically possible options and that the visualition should at some point in the future build on the fly on  server for a user's selection of the data 90 seconds simply is way too much.
I have allready reduced the visualition template for the calculate line crossings functions to all what is necessary leaving asside all captions and so on. That did help, but not as much as expected.

The lines are drawn as follows: First, all boxes are drawn keeping their id from the original data. Then I go back to my data, look where connections are and build the lines.

Answer (score 1):

You could transform your XML into the DOT language (plain TXT format) by XSLT and process it by GraphViz. I solved some similar issue (although not so huge as yours seems to be) this way.

Comment: I've used the same technique on some quite complex graphs: though I didn't transform directly into DOT, but into DotML (http://martin-loetzsch.de/DOTML/). I found it a bit tricky to "tweak" the routing of the lines, but there's a lot of capability in the tool that I didn't explore. Certainly beats writing it for yourself.

Comment: Thank! I will certainly give that a try. But I'm not quite sure GraphViz could do all I do now in my own code (each box has a link leading back to my data, there are mouse-over-effects and as you can see the background depends on the data).